# Javascript comments in Haml

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, comments, haml, codekit

Can any one tell me why this isn't compiling in HAML?

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
    $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2'});
    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3'});
    $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4'});
    $(".group5").colorbox({rel:'group5'});
    $(".group6").colorbox({rel:'group6'});
    $(".group7").colorbox({rel:'group7'});
    $(".group8").colorbox({rel:'group8'});
  });
```

The error I am getting is:

"Syntax error on line 33: Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces. Use --trace for backtrace."

Line 33 is where the comment is.

I am using codekit on a mac

Comment: “1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.” So what happens when you replace the tab character with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#{ # this is your comment text 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`- # Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements`

Answer (score 0):

To comment in HAML use just one forward slash and put one space in between the slash ant your comment example
/ Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements